# after changing ng-repeat directive with dir-paginate {{expression}} breaks

Tags: angularjs

I am making a table with angularJS.
This is my current code on plunker:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/A9QhzHnhwk3rYL9Wjo93
```

I want to add a new feature: pagination.

I added `angularUtils.directives.dirPagination` dependency to my model `myTable`, and I added dirPaginate library *dirPagination.js* to *index.html*,
but I have a problem when I change `ng-repeat` derective to `dir-paginate`, then my {{ expression }} brakes.

What could be the problem here?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hiding the link inside a code block in order to avoid posting code samples in the question body is not appropriate.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your angular version, cause your lib is not compatible to `1.0.2`, that you're using, cause it doesn't have `$watchCollection` method for `$scope`. Change version to `1.4.*` and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't pay attention on that.